# Python class, Input for Self retaining previous text

Tags: python, class, input, self

Might be a simple issue for a Python Programmer but its driving me crazy.
I have a class and if I change the self.type question it does not reflect on my other python script. Its till will ask the old input question not the new.
Help pls...

```
class Piano:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = input("Size?") --> eg. change to input("S/M/L?")

    def printdetails(self):
        print (self.type, "piano,")
```

To call

```
from mystuff import Piano
cfcpiano = Piano()
```

Comment: How do you change the question? By question I assume you mean the argument to `input`. It's hardcoded within the class. Are you sure you are saving the file or executing the updated file?

Comment: If you are trying to rerun `from mystuff import Piano` from the same interactive session, it will not reload the module.  You need to either start a new session, or you need to use `reload` (python 2 only)

Comment: If you have many different scripts in different directories, make sure you are re-running the same script you are making the changes in

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I think I found a solution by restarting kernel, not sure if that is the most elegant solution in Python but for now it works.